# How to solve a cauchy euler equation with multiple variables?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For this question I'm having trouble solving this equation. Here is what I have so far. Can anyone please help me out?

$ u'' + 2ku' + k^2u = e^{-kt} lnt$

$ u = k^m$

$ u' = mk^{m-1}$

$ u'' = m(m-1)k^{m-2}$

$ m(m-1)k^{m-2} + 2kmk^{m-1} + k^2k^m = 0$

Comment: What is $u'$ exactly ?

Comment: u' is the main variable in the equation

Comment: is it $u'=du/dt$ or else ?

Comment: Try by taking the trial solution $~u=e^{mt}~$ for the homogeneous equation. Then find separately the Complementary Function and the Particular Integral. Good Luck.

Comment: Ok so $ u = e^{mt}$ as a substitution?

Comment: @ Aryadeva Ya, u' = du/dt

Answer (score 1):

$$u'' + 2ku' + k^2u = e^{-kt} \ln t$$
This is not a Cauchy-Euler's differential equation. I suppose $k \ne 0$:
$$e^{kt}(u'' + 2ku' + k^2u) =  \ln t$$
$$e^{kt}(u'' + ku')+ke^{kt}(u'+ ku) =  \ln t$$
$$(e^{kt}u')'+k(e^{kt}u)' =  \ln t$$
$$(e^{kt}u'+ke^{kt}u)' =  \ln t$$
$$(e^{kt}u)'' =  \ln t$$
Integrate twice.

Note that:
$$\int \ln t dt=t \ln t -t+C$$

Comment: For $k=0$ the DE becomes simply $u''=\ln t$.